# Break words with twig

Tags: css, filter, twig, word-break

Is there a way that long words could got be break in twig? That after few characters it is breaking it up and sets a hyphen. Exists maybe a filter that would this do?

Like:

`Thisisareallylongword`

to:

```
Thisisa- 
reallylong-
word
```

Cause the Characters gonna be directly outputted from the database...

Comment: It's about CSS, it's not the job of twig...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah the solution would be with css. the attribute `word-break: break-all` breaks the word in the frame of the element. there´s an additional attribute with `hyphens: auto` which should set the hyphens at the breaking positions.

(Which works for me actually not...)

**UPDATE:**

there is an even better way with `word-wrap: break-word` which is just breaking the long words and the other words would be just jumpin normal in the next row.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a twig filter such as slice that allows you to show only N number of characters of a string.

after slicing you can add - and a line break

then you can use the merge filter to get it all back into 1 string

but twigs won't really help you break words I'd rather use simple CSS

Comment: yeah for twig it could be the right solution. but i would it do in css way too

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wordwrap filter from the [Text extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/text.html#the-text-extension):

```
{{ "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing" | wordwrap(10) }}
```

Gives you:

```
Lorem ipsu
m dolor si
t amet, co
nsectetur
adipiscing
```

See [this fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/lox8ci).

Comment: yeah but first there are no hyphens and second these _word-breaks_ are unnecessary for my way.

Comment: ok but not work cause symfony not knows the filter -,-
`The filter "wordwrap" does not exist in Bundle:view:template.html.twig`

Comment: You should add the twig extensions: `composer require twig/extensions`

Comment: I don't understand. You shooted the project using `composer require`??

Comment: no shooted project cause composer require didn´t worked cause an earlier version of twig was blocking it. so i tried through updating composer.json but that didn´t worked well...